# Checar a integridade de arquivos de vídeo em lote

Tags: powershell, vídeo

Como checar de forma automática e customizável via **Shell/Linguagem de Programação** a integridade (arquivo **Incompleto/Corrompido**) de arquivos de vídeo (`.avi`, `.mp4`, `.mkv` entre outros) ?

> **OBS:** Tendo como fator limitante a falta de um **HASH** prévio dos arquivos.

Comment: Mudei o titulo, porque automática e customizável já são praticamente "embutidos" dentro da "programação"

Comment: Sem preblema @GuilhermeNascimento

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Haja vista que não existe um **HASH** prévio (de quando se havia certeza do estado do arquivo) é necessário o uso de um programa de Terceiro [FFMPEG](http://ffmpeg.org/) e de um script executado via `Powershell` que automatiza a execução da checagem dos arquivos de vídeo de determinada pasta:

**Script:**

```
$logPath = "C:\Users\User\projeto1\error.log"
$videosFolder = "C:\Users\User\videos"
$ffmpegPath = "C:\ffmpeg\bin\ffmpeg.exe"
$arquivos = Get-ChildItem -path $videosFolder | 
    Where-Object {
        ($_.extension -eq ".mp4" -or $_.extension -eq ".mkv")
    }
foreach($item in $arquivos){
    "+#+#+ " + $item.FullName >> $logPath
    &$ffmpegPath -v error -i $item.FullName -f null 2 >> $logPath 2>&1
}
```

1. No script eu determino os endereços da pasta onde estão os vídeos, onde esta o executável do `FFMPEG` e onde será criado o arquivo de LOG com os erros de cada vídeo
2. Seleciono os arquivos com base em minhas necessidades (somente videos com extensão `.mp4` e `.mkv`)
3. Para cada arquivo executo o `FFMPEG` passando alguns parâmetros de controle como o quão verboso deve ser a verificação.

> **Notas:**
>
> - A verificação é quadro a quadro logo os erros são por quadro.
> - Foi organizado de forma que os erros fossem impressos abaixo do nome do arquivo. (pode não haver erro algum, ou haver vários erros
>     em cada quadro o que gera um arquivo de Log enorme).
> - **NUNCA** deixe os erros serem exibidos na saída padrão, deixe sempre para serem armazenados no arquivo de Log.
> - Adicionei uma string **+#+#+** diferenciada ao inicio de cada caminho de arquivo para facilitar a busca.

**Dados dos Testes:**

Foram testados 4 arquivos:

- 2 Perfeitos (11 MB cada)
- 1 Incompleto (Revido do **Bittorrent** antes do final (ainda é parcialmente reproduzível)) (55 MB)
- 1 Corrompido (Abri o arquivo no **Notepad++** e adicionei caracteres aleatórios) (11 MB)

Tempo de teste:

- Exibindo as mensagens de Erro no Arquivo de Log: 17 Segundos
- Exibindo as mensagens de Erro no Console do Powershell: 14 Minutos

Tamanho do arquivo de Log: 19 MB